# How to highlight a value only if it appears 6 times within a 13 column window

Tags: google-sheets, highlight

I am creating a rota on Google sheets and I am looking to highlight a name whenever that name comes up more than 6 times within a 13 column window.

At the moment the formula is =COUNTIF($B4:$Z4,"Louis")>6
But I only want the name highlighted if it appears 6 times within any 13 columns that are adjacent (i.e it appears 6 times between B4 and N4).

Any help with this would be much appreciated thank you!!

Comment: Please clarify if another example can be 6 times between C4 and O4, if there are other names in the same row, if any cell of the row could be empty

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that column `A` (from A4) contains the names to be counted, if the respective cells are to be colored when the name is repeated in AT LEAST 6 cells of 13 consecutive columns (whatever the beginning of their position between `B` and `N`), then you might consider this formula:

```
=and($B4:$Z4<>"",$B4:$Z4=$A4,
or(
countif($B4:$N4,$A4)>=6,
countif($C4:$O4,$A4)>=6,
countif($D4:$P4,$A4)>=6,
countif($E4:$Q4,$A4)>=6,
countif($F4:$R4,$A4)>=6,
countif($G4:$S4,$A4)>=6,
countif($H4:$T4,$A4)>=6,
countif($I4:$U4,$A4)>=6,
countif($J4:$V4,$A4)>=6,
countif($K4:$W4,$A4)>=6,
countif($L4:$X4,$A4)>=6,
countif($M4:$Y4,$A4)>=6,
countif($N4:$Z4,$A4)>=6
))
```

[image: conditional]

This [**link**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N6yXlmZsP_dtkmPkJ44VwDDES1kxa5YjxCOEnozG_uo/edit#gid=0) takes you to the test file

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, you do not know in advance which of the names can appear in the row 7 or more times.

Therefore, you need to filter this name from the general range using the [**FILTER() function**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en#null) on the [**COUNTIF() > 6**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en#null) condition.

A formula like `=FILTER(B4:N4,COUNTIF($B4:$N4,B4:N4)>6)` solves this problem

[image: Example]

Comment: and all the other groups of 13 columns each? The OP said that they  go from B to Z

Comment: ... and where is the reference to the name to find?

Comment: @Daniele Regarding the last column Z - yes, thanks, I missed that. However, until the OP answers the question of what to do if another name is repeated in the next range, I can not improve the answer. Reference to the name to find? I understood the task as "any of the names that is more than 6" - so the solution is exactly this: find in the range which word occurs the required number of times and mark it with conditional formatting.